# Finding the most recently written file (unix) : find appearing "not quite good enough"

Tags: unix, find

I ran the following command :

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -ltrhg
```

In order to get the most recently written file when a program was running.

The result was odd : at the bottom of the list, I got recent files, but the MOST VERY recently created file was missing... That is to test, I directly ran

```
touch asdf
```

followed by

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -ltrhg
```

yet asdf was not the most recent.

Any thoughts on why this command seems to ignore the most recently written file, yet is returning several hundred files, in the correct order which they were edited?

Comment: I just tried your `touch ...` `find ...` sequence, and it worked for me (in a directory with only a few files).  Does `asdf` show up at all?  Is some process concurrently creating or updating files in that directory?  BTW, this would be more appropriate on superuser.com; I've voted to close and migrate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programs call write() ultimately when they are writing to a file. write does not immediately put anything to disk.

Unless you program calls fdatasync() or one its cousins like fflush() the data stays in kernel buffers until the kernel decides to put the data to disk.  You can write a bunch of data a file without it begin physically written to disk.  This is a performance feature. Disk I/O is very slow compared to memory access.

This means, in practice, your program can find other disk files newer than the one it is currently writing.

Comment: sounds good - so then ..... are you suggesting that the other steps are correct, but they must be prefixed by fdatasync or fflush?

Comment: A sync operation (fflush or whatever) forces the write to disk. Note that sometimes updating file metadata is deferred until the file is closed.  This is filesystem depdendent, and depends on options used to mount the filesystem.   Metadata is what stat() (find uses stat() ) uses to determine file mtimes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that there are so many files that xargs partitions them into several invocations of ls.

(I doubt the buffer cache is the problem. Unless this is some exotic distributed version of Unix, find, xargs, and ls should all be reading and writing the same buffer cache.)

Comment: This is not correct.  Read Stevens 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment' and see what actually occurs in UNIX File I/O.